# Como retornar uma consulta em formato JSON com valores extras e keys customizadas?

Tags: json, python, django

Estou querendo retornar o resultado em `JSON` seguindo este formato:

```
{"cadastros": [
    {"id": 1, "STATUS": true, "pessoas": [], "podeEscrever": true},
    {"id": 2, "STATUS": false, "pessoas": ['Maria', 'Ana'], "podeEscrever": true},
], 'principal': true}
```

**models.py**:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    status = models.BooleanField()
    pessoas = models.ManyToManyField(Pessoa, blank=True)
    podeescrever = models.BooleanField()
```

Veja que no formato `JSON` existe `podeEscrever` com letra maiúscula, logo o resultado deve respeitar esse formato também.

A ideia principal é usar a biblioteca `simplejson` para manipular o resultado e retornar o `JSON` no formato desejado.

**views.py**:

```
def minha_views(request):
    p = Pessoa.objects.values()
    data = simplejson.dumps(p)
    # aqui seria formatado
    return HttpResponse(data, content_type='application/json; charset=utf8')
```

A minha dificuldade está em formatar o `JSON`, eu consigo retornar os resultados da query direto pra `JSON`, mas não sei como manipular para adicionar novas chaves e alterar o nome do campo `podeescrever` para `podeEscrever`.

Outra coisa que está acontecendo é que o campo `pessoas` que é `ManytoManyField` não retorna no `JSON` se estiver vazio, o correto era retornar com uma lista vazia `[]` se não houver itens.

Não parece ser difícil realizar esse procedimento, alguém sabe como resolver este problema?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eu usaria compreensões de lista em ambos os casos:

```
return HttpResponse(json.dumps({
    "principal": True,
    "cadastros":[{
        "id":p.id,
        "STATUS":p.status,
        "podeEscrever":p.podeescrever,
        "pessoas":[unicode(pessoa) for pessoa in p.pessoas.all()],
    } for p in MyModel.objects.all().prefetch_related("pessoas")],
}), content_type='application/json; charset=utf8')
```

Essa solução pode ser meio trabalhosa se os modelos forem grandes, mas tem a vantagem de permitir tanto customizar os nomes dos atributos, quais aparecem e quais não, e também seu formato (é muito comum eu ter de formatar datas, por exemplo, numa forma não padrão ao gerar o JSON).

Notas: 1) eu costumo usar `json` e não `simplejson`, não sei se faz diferença; 2) Repare no uso de `prefetch_related` para reduzir o número de queries ao mínimo necessário.

Comment: No caso o modelo real é grande, mas fazer desse seu jeito parece mais eficiente. Eu instalei a nova versão do `simplejson` porque estava tendo um problema com `decimal`, só não me recordo agora se era com o `json` ou com `simplejson` do projeto. Em relação ao `prefetch_related` ainda não compreendi bem o seu funcionamento, sempre que for consultar um campo `ManyToMany` (`p.pessoas.all()`) devo usar `prefetch_related` para melhorar a performance?

Comment: @Orion Não é só com um `ManyToMany`, mas com qualquer campo que faça um join entre tabelas (ex.: `ForeignKey`). Digamos que o modelo `A` tenha um campo `b` referenciando um modelo `B`. Digamos também que `A` tenha 1000 linhas, cada uma referenciando uma linha distinta de `B` (também 1000). Se você fizer `for a in A.objects.all(): print (a.b)` o Django vai fazer **1001** consultas ao BD! Mas com `for a in A.objects.all().prefetch_related("b"): print (a.b)` ele só vai fazer **2**. Não tenho certeza se o mesmo ocorre com a chamada do `values`, mas acho que sim (teria que testar).

Answer (score 2):

Consegui resolver da seguinte maneira:

```
pessoas = Pessoa.objects.values()
pessoas_modificado = []

for p in pessoas:

    # altera o nome das chaves:
    p['STATUS'] = p.pop('status')
    p['podeEscrever'] = p.pop('podeescrever')

    # retorna lista vazia caso não exista pessoas
    p['pessoas'] = p.get('pessoas', [])

    # adiciona o dicionario a nova lista:
    pessoas_modificado.append(p)

# cria a formatação esperada
dicionario = {'cadastros': list(pessoas_modificado), 'principal': True}

# retorna em JSON
return HttpResponse(simplejson.dumps(dicionario), content_type='application/json; charset=utf8')
```